# Apache 2.4, PHP 5.6.17 Debian 8.3, How to remove encoding in default PHP header?

Tags: php, html, character-encoding, header

I am playing with few hobby websites. Due to the fact that I am a beginner in programming, sometimes I have problem with my scripts hogging hosting resources.
To avoid potential problems, I have decided to rent a budget dedicated server (Atom N2800 with 2 GB RAM).
I have installed Debian 8.3 (Polish language), then Apache 2.4 and PHP 5.6.

As far, everything works. A html file is displayed normally. However when I change extension to .php, the default header sent has UTF-8 encoding (thus, ignoring information in `<meta>` that the text is encoded in latin2.). I can correct it by adding `header()` function at the beginning, but fully rewriting modified phpBB is at that moment beyond my abilities.

Examples:
http://37.187.105.171/1.html - file encoded in Latin2, no information about encoding in HTML header, so it uses `<meta>` information.
http://37.187.105.171/1.php - the same file with extension changed to php - in the heder is an information about UTF-8 encoding.
Also, 1_h.php (can't post more than 2 links) is the same file with added: `<?PHP header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-2'); ?>` at start.

How can I remove encoding from the default PHP header?

Comment: Do you want to remove it or to fix it? Because PHP can make your life easier if you just `ini_set('default_charset', 'iso-8859-2');` in your project configuration.

Answer (score 0):

change this line in `php.ini` file :

```
default_charset = "utf-8"
```

Comment: And is there a way, as the OP wants, to not sent a default encoding? Leaving the choice of encoding to the <meta> element?

Answer (score 0):

in php:

```
<?php header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8'); ?>
```

in html:

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" >
```

default encoding:

in phpRoot/php.ini:

```
default_charset = "utf-8"
```